# Unmerge ggplot Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

[image]

I currently have a ggplot and am trying to format the legend, however I want to separate the lines ie. red dashed line- slope, blue dashed line-mean. The legend seems to be showing where they intercept, how do I separate them?

I have included an image of my plot for clarity.

```
base3<- ggplot(data = Pace_Less2km, aes(x=event_id, y=avg_racep, 
group=1)) +
geom_line(color='orange')+
geom_point(color='orange')+
#geom_hline(yintercept = mean(Pace_Less2km$avg_racep), 
color="blue")+
geom_hline(aes(yintercept= mean(Pace_Less2km$avg_racep), linetype = 
"Mean"), colour= 'blue') +
geom_abline(aes(intercept = 1.09, slope = .0005, linetype="Slope"), 
color="red")+
scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c(2, 2) ,
                    guide = guide_legend())
base3
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293125/r-change-ggplot-legend-names-with-scale-linetype-manual) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fully reproducible example showing one way to draw multiple summary lines in ggplot2, with separate legend entries for each line.

The main idea is to create a second, auxiliary data.frame containing your summary data and use it along with `geom_abline()` and `scale_color_manual()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create an auxiliary data.frame containing the summary statistics.
m0 = lm(Petal.Length ~ 1, data=iris)
m1 = lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data=iris)

line_dat = data.frame(summary_line=c("Mean", "Slope"),
                      intercept=c(m0$coefficients[1], m1$coefficients[1]),
                      slope=c(0, m1$coefficients[2]), row.names=NULL)

line_dat
#   summary_line intercept   slope
# 1         Mean  3.758000 0.00000
# 2        Slope  1.083558 2.22994

p = ggplot(data=iris, aes(y=Petal.Length, x=Petal.Width)) +
    geom_point(size=3, color="grey30") +
    geom_abline(data=line_dat, 
                aes(slope=slope, intercept=intercept, color=summary_line),
                linetype="dashed", size=1) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c(Mean="blue", Slope="red"))
```

[image]